# How to use bsearch correctly in c?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, bsearch

I want to search for a date (which is a struct) in an array of dates to see if it is in it. This is the first time I am using `bsearch` and it always returns the same result, `0`, whereas it should either return `null` or a pointer to the date found. I am using the same comparing function I used to sort the array and the sorting works fine. I'm guessing if the function returns `0 it means it has found the date in the array. What have I done wrong? If the mistake is not obvious I can post the full code.

```
#define MIN_SIZE 0
#define MAX_SIZE 10000
#define MAX_MONTH_STR 9
#define SWAP 1
#define NO_SWAP -1
#define EQUAL 0

//Define a struct data type
typedef struct
{
    //Declaration of struct members
    char* month;
    int day;
    int year;
}date;

//Method to allocate memory for a list of date structures
date* allocateStruct(int size)
{
    //Declaration of variables
    date *array;
    int i;

    //Allocate memory for array to store 'size' many 'date' struct data types
    array = malloc(size*sizeof(date));

    //For-loop to allocate memory for each struct's members and initialize them to zero
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        array[i].month = calloc(MAX_MONTH_STR,sizeof(char));
        array[i].day = (int) calloc(1,sizeof(int));
        array[i].year = (int) calloc(1,sizeof(int));
    }

    return array;
}

//Method to free memory allocated
void freeStruct(date* array, int size)
{
    //Declaration of variable
    int i;

    //For-loop to free up struct members
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        free(array[i].month);
        free(&array[i].day);
        free(&array[i].year);
    }

    //Free up structs
    free(array);
}

//Method to compare two dates
int cmpDates (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    //Declaration and dereference of variables
    date first = *(date*)a;
    date second = *(date*)b;
    int y_result, m_result, d_result;

    //Calculate results
    y_result = second.year-first.year;
    m_result = second.month-first.month;
    d_result = second.day-first.day;

    //If-statements to determine whether to swap dates based on year
    //If-statement to determine whether both years are in 90s group
    if (first.year>=90 && first.year<=99 && second.year>=90 && second.year<=99)
    {
        //If-statement to determine whether years are equal
        if (y_result!=0)
        {
            return (y_result);
        }
    }
    //Else-if-statement to determine whether both years are in 00-12 group
    else if (first.year>=0 && first.year<=12 && second.year>=0 && second.year<=12)
    {
        //If-statement to determine whether years are equal
        if (y_result!=0)
        {
            return (y_result);
        }
    }
    //Otherwise the two years belong to different year groups
    else
    {
        //If-statement to determine whether first year belongs to 00-12 group
        if (first.year>=0 && first.year<=12)
        {
            return NO_SWAP;
        }
        else
        {
            return SWAP;
        }
    }

    //If-statement to determine whether to swap dates based on months
    if (m_result!=0)
    {
        return m_result;
    }

    //If-statement to determine whether to swap dates based on days
    if (d_result!=0)
    {
    return d_result;
    }

    //If dates are exactly the same
    return EQUAL;
}

enum months { 
    January=1, 
    February, 
    March, 
    April, 
    May, 
    June, 
    July, 
    August, 
    September, 
    October, 
    November, 
    December 
};
int main()
{
    //Declaration of variables
    int n; //number of dates in array
    date* date_list; //array of dates
    date *key_date; //date to search for
    date *q_result; //result of search

    //Read input
    do
    {
        //printf("Enter number of dates you want to enter (between 1 and 10000):\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }while(n<MIN_SIZE || n>MAX_SIZE);

    //Allocate memory for an array of n dates
    date_list = allocateStruct(n);

    //For-loop to store values in 'date_list'
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //printf("Enter the date (month day year) in the following format <text number number>:");
        scanf("%s", date_list[i].month);
        scanf("%d", &date_list[i].day);
        scanf("%d", &date_list[i].year);
    }

    //Allocate memory for one date
    key_date = allocateStruct(1);

    //Read date for query
    //printf("Enter date you want to query:");
    scanf("%s", key_date->month);
    scanf("%d", &key_date->day);
    scanf("%d", &key_date->year);

    //Sort the array with built-in function qsort
    qsort(date_list, n, sizeof(date), cmpDates);

    //Print list of sorted dates
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //printf("Enter the date (month day year) in the following format: text number number");
        printf("%s ", date_list[i].month);
        printf("%d ", date_list[i].day);
        printf("%02d\n", date_list[i].year); //need & ?
    }

    //Query with bsearch --> I TRIED BOTH OF THESE LINES BUT THE RESULT WAS THE SAME
    q_result = (date*) bsearch(&key_date, date_list, n, sizeof(date), cmpDates);
    // q_result = bsearch(&key_date, date_list, n, sizeof(date), cmpDates);

    //Printing answer to query
    if(q_result!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Yes in list");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No not in list");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `cmpDates`? are you initializing `key_date` and `date_list` correctly? what is your question? Please post the actual code.

Comment: need to show cmpDates for us to answer

Comment: yes the date_list and key_date are initialized correctly, i printed them out to make sure and they are correct. i will post the full code then

Comment: Is the array you search sorted?

Comment: it is sorted from latest date to oldest @jpw

Comment: the program only works with years from 1990-2012, thats why the cmpDates is the way it is..

Comment: Fill the ... ... part please.

Comment: `array[i].day = (int) calloc(1,sizeof(int));` array[i].day is not a pointer. It is an int.

Comment: ... and squelching the resulting warning with a `(int)` cast is not the way to fix it.

Comment: @wildplasser i was getting cast warnings, that is why i added the int cast

Comment: but it **is not a pointer** you are forcing a square peg into a round hole. kindof.

Comment: You were getting a warning because you tried to assign a pointer to an int. As said previously, casting is not the solution here.

Comment: @Yiannis you were getting cast warnings because you're trying to save a pointer to an `int` member. An `int` member holds... an `int`.

Comment: Your month comparison looks dubious.  Did you sort the data with your comparison function?  Have you tested your comparison function with all relevant cases?  Why are you not storing the year as a full 4-digit number?  Your presentation code might drop the leading two digits (it shouldn't, but it might), but internally, you should learn from the Y2K fiasco and store the full year.  You won't save any space with the scheme you're using, and you grotesquely complicate your code.

Comment: but why is that assigning a pointer? its sizeof(int) not sizeof(int*) isnt it? @EricFortin i am new to c by the way

Comment: @JonathanLeffler its for a uni assignment and we are required to store the year in that format. and yes the data does get sorted correctly

Comment: When you allocate a `date`, you automatically allocate the space for the year and the day.  You should be storing the month as a number, not as a `char *`, but you do need to allocate for your `char *`.

Comment: I'd like to see the exact assignment that states that.  It is putrid.  You can simplify your life by converting the year number into a normalized value in your comparison function.  You should not be futzing around with as many comparisons as there are in your code.  (For example: `if (first.year < 50) first.year += 2000; else first.year += 1900;` -- since you make copies of the structures, this isn't going to affect the main storage.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Input n (1<=n<=10000) and then followed by n lines. Each line corresponds to a valid date, consisting of
one string ("January", "February", ..., or "December"), one integer between 1 and 31, and one two digit
integer representing the year (from 90 to 99, and then from 00 to 12). You do not have to worry about date
validation. All dates in the input are valid dates.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes i didn't think that was the best way i was dealing with the year but i couldnt think of anything better at the time, i'l try what you suggested after I sort out the query :)

Comment: @Yiannis Did you try my answer ? If it is not the problem, tell me I'll remove it.

Comment: @EricFortin im sorry but i dont know what you mean, im just confused with all this pointer business in c :)

Comment: Incidentally, the longest month name, September (assuming English), has 9 characters, so you need to allocate 10 bytes of storage for it, to allow for the trailing null you need to terminate the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code I assembled based on yours that seems to work.  I've not stress tested it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN_SIZE 1
#define MAX_SIZE 10000
#define MAX_MONTH_STR 10

#define EQUAL 0
#define LESS_THAN -1
#define MORE_THAN +1

typedef struct
{
    char *month;
    int day;
    int year;
} date;

static
date *allocateStruct(int size)
{
    date *array = malloc(size * sizeof(date));
    if (array == 0)
        exit(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i].month = calloc(MAX_MONTH_STR, sizeof(char));
        if (array[i].month == 0)
            exit(1);
    }

    return array;
}

static
void freeStruct(date *array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        free(array[i].month);
    }
    free(array);
}

static inline int normalize_year(int year)
{
    return (year < 50) ? year + 2000 : year + 1900;
}

static inline int month_number(const char *name)
{
    static const char *months[] =
    {
        "",
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December",
    };
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        if (strcmp(name, months[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid (unrecognized) month name <<%s>>\n", name);
    exit(1);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}

static
int cmpDates(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    date first = *(date *)a;
    date second = *(date *)b;

    int y1 = normalize_year(first.year);
    int y2 = normalize_year(second.year);
    if (y1 < y2)
        return LESS_THAN;
    else if (y1 > y2)
        return MORE_THAN;

    int m1 = month_number(first.month);
    int m2 = month_number(second.month);
    if (m1 < m2)
        return LESS_THAN;
    else if (m1 > m2)
        return MORE_THAN;

    if (first.day < second.day)
        return LESS_THAN;
    else if (first.day > second.day)
        return MORE_THAN;
    else
        return EQUAL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    date *date_list;
    date *key_date;
    date *q_result;

    do
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
            exit(1);
    } while (n < MIN_SIZE || n > MAX_SIZE);

    date_list = allocateStruct(n);

    printf("Input data:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", date_list[i].month);
        scanf("%d", &date_list[i].day);
        scanf("%d", &date_list[i].year);
        printf("%.2d: %.2d %s %.2d\n", i, date_list[i].day, date_list[i].month, date_list[i].year);
    }

    qsort(date_list, n, sizeof(date), cmpDates);

    printf("Sorted:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%.2d: %.2d %s %.2d\n", i, date_list[i].day, date_list[i].month, date_list[i].year);

    key_date = allocateStruct(1);

    scanf("%s", key_date->month);
    scanf("%d", &key_date->day);
    scanf("%d", &key_date->year);
    printf("Search: %.2d %s %.2d\n", key_date->day, key_date->month, key_date->year);

    q_result = (date *) bsearch(key_date, date_list, n, sizeof(date), cmpDates);

    if (q_result != NULL)
    {
        printf("Yes (%.2d %s %.2d) in list (%.2d %s %.2d)\n",
                key_date->day, key_date->month, key_date->year,
                q_result->day, q_result->month, q_result->year);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No (%.2d %s %.2d) in list\n",
                key_date->day, key_date->month, key_date->year);
    }
    freeStruct(date_list, n);
    freeStruct(key_date, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample data:

```
16
November 26 00
February 18 12
January 19 08
March 22 11
October 08 05
December 22 10
November 08 01
May 21 10
July 10 92
October 06 91
November 30 93
April 25 90
March 21 90
September 18 97
June 23 97
July 19 98
November 29 93
```

The last line of the file is the date to search for.  The `November 29 93` is not in the list, but change `29` to `30` and the date is in the list.  In both cases, the code reports this correctly.

Sample output:

```
Input data:
00: 26 November 00
01: 18 February 12
02: 19 January 08
03: 22 March 11
04: 08 October 05
05: 22 December 10
06: 08 November 01
07: 21 May 10
08: 10 July 92
09: 06 October 91
10: 30 November 93
11: 25 April 90
12: 21 March 90
13: 18 September 97
14: 23 June 97
15: 19 July 98
Sorted:
00: 21 March 90
01: 25 April 90
02: 06 October 91
03: 10 July 92
04: 30 November 93
05: 23 June 97
06: 18 September 97
07: 19 July 98
08: 26 November 00
09: 08 November 01
10: 08 October 05
11: 19 January 08
12: 21 May 10
13: 22 December 10
14: 22 March 11
15: 18 February 12
Search: 29 November 93
No (29 November 93) in list
```

I think it is a lousy idea to store the month name in the date structure.  If you are going to store a pointer, you could store a pointer to one of a fixed array of strings representing the month names.  You'd read the input name into an array, then find the canonical pointer from a list of the month names.  You'd store the names so that the address of `January` is before the address for `February`, etc, so that you could compare pointers and come up with the correct answer.  However, I've not implemented that.  In fact, I think storing month names in the structure is a bad idea; I'd store a month number.  I also think storing just two digits of the year is a lousy decision.  Maybe you weren't aware of the Y2K bug fixing work that was necessary because people tried to cut corners and only stored two digits for years instead of four digits, but it was messy.  It is far, far simpler just to store the year number.  You aren't even saving any space since you're using 4 bytes (an `int` is usually 4 bytes these days) to store the 2-digit year.  If you have year as a 4-digit number, and month and day as 2-digit numbers, then `yyyy * 10000 + mm * 100 + dd` gives you an 8-digit integer that can be sorted trivially.  If you need to compute the number of days between two dates, then the broken-down format isn't as convenient as a count of the days since a reference date (such as 1900-01-01 was day 1).  You can take the difference between two such date values to get the number of days between them.

Comment: i was using enum for the months i just forgot to include it in the code i copied because i was copying it in parts.. i copied it into the code last night after talking with eric fortin and i have adjusted a few other things in my code, but still havent got it to working. i will have a look at your solution after uni, thanks for that!

Comment: okay i got rid of the `enum` of the months and just used an `array` like in your code and also made a function to normalize the year comparison and it simplified the `cmpDates` function and the whoke thing is working now, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 4):

`key_date` is a pointer but you pass its address to bsearch so when `cmpDates` is called, it will try to cast(reinterpret) a `void*` which is a `date**` to a `date*` and then dereference it to a `date`. Obviously, the values retrieved from that `date` struct will be all wrong. I am surprised you didn't have a crash with the month string.

```
q_result = (date*) bsearch(&key_date, date_list, n, sizeof(date), cmpDates);
```

should be

```
q_result = (date*) bsearch(key_date, date_list, n, sizeof(date), cmpDates);
```

---

Obviously, you still need to sort out(no pun intended) the calloc issue

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    array[i].month = calloc(MAX_MONTH_STR,sizeof(char));
    array[i].day = (int) calloc(1,sizeof(int));
    array[i].year = (int) calloc(1,sizeof(int));
}
```

should be(if you really need to keep month as a string)

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    array[i].month = calloc(MAX_MONTH_STR,sizeof(char));
    array[i].day = 0;
    array[i].year = 0;
}
```

and then

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    free(array[i].month);
    free(&array[i].day);
    free(&array[i].year);
}
```

should be

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    free(array[i].month);
}
```

Regarding your month comparison, you need a function like this:

```
months GetMonth(char* m)
{
    if (strcmp(m, "January") == 0)
        return months.January;
    else if (strcmp(m, "February") == 0)
        return months.February;
    ....
}
```

I have left out case sensitiveness.

Then you store this enum in your date struct and the month comparison will at least make sense.

Comment: those are the lines i have in my code.. i thought u were saying change them for these 2

Comment: i've made all the changes but it still returns "no" instead of "yes".. why dont we need to allocate space for day and year and we just them to 0, i dont get that @Eric Fortn

Comment: The space is automatically allocated when you allocate space for date struct. I did set them to 0 to have a default(invalid) value otherwise it could be anything and then your `cmpDate` function would use those bogus values. By using a default one, you can make sure the default values are sorted first or last depending on your requirements.

Comment: so what else could be going wrong? i read here that the array should be in ascending order (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_bsearch.htm) mine goes from newest date to oldest

Comment: Are you sure your sorting works because the comparison for month is bogus. It is comparing addresses of strings instead of the actual content of them which makes no sense. As stated you should at least have a function to go from month name to an int and then compare those values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72627/discussion-between-yiannis-and-eric-fortin).